# How to use SQLAlchemy model in RabbitMQ consumer file in Flask?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using RabbitMQ with Flask 2.0.3 and pika 1.2.0

I am unable to save or select data from the database using models from consumers.py.

Seems, the flash application is not loaded in the consumers.py. I am getting the following error.

```
File "/Users/iynga/projects/python/linkme-app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 174, in __init__self.app = app = db.get_app()
File "/Users/iynga/projects/python/linkme-app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1042, in get_app
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

Here is my consumer.py

```
import json
import pika
from database import db, Process

params = pika.URLParameters('url')

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='link-me')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print('Received in link-me')
    data = json.loads(body)
    print(data)
    if properties.content_type == 'process_created':
        process = Process(
            payload={
                'x': 1,
                'y': 2
            },
            connection_id=1,
        )
        db.session.add(process)
        db.session.commit()
        print('process_created')


channel.basic_consume(queue='link-me', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

print('Started Consuming')

channel.start_consuming()

channel.close()
```

Thank you in advance